# Issue with Claims after migrating project to MVC5, unexpected call to GetRolesForUser

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5.2

A project has been updated from MVC 4 to MVC 5 because of new the use of Visual Studio 2015 which was not compiling razor views properly (which is something that's documented by Microsoft and not the issue).
We use an utility class accross projects to retrieve values stored in Identity Claims.

In that class, someone did a call to:

```
System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims.ToList()
```

which was working in the previous MVC4 version, but after migrating all the Nuget packages required for MVC5, this specific call throws the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in  System.Web.Providers.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Value cannot be null.
>
> Parameter name : username
>
> System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String
>   username) +183    System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal.GetRoles() +215
>   System.Web.Security.d__1.MoveNext() +58
>   System.Security.Claims.d__1.MoveNext() +253
>   System.Security.Claims.d__1.MoveNext() +209
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +445
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58

I did a foreach() on that collection instead, and it's like after all custom defined Claims it's reaching to an unexpected end, or it's trying to retrieve things from the GetRoleForUser and I don't know why.

If anyone has a hint, I can give more details if needed.

Setup of the Web.Config of that MVC project:

```
<modules>
      <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ClaimsAuthorizationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.ClaimsAuthorizationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
....

<system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="http://localhost:58663/" />
      </audienceUris>
      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <add type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </securityTokenHandlers>
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
      <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry">
        <authority name="QuadraSTS">
          <keys>
            <add thumbprint="XXXHIDDENXXX" />
          </keys>
          <validIssuers>
            <add name="QuadraSTS" />
          </validIssuers>
        </authority>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
      <claimsAuthorizationManager type="ClaimsBasedAuthorization.AuthorizationManager,QuadraBox" />
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" persistentSessionLifetime="1.0:0:0" path="/" />
      <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" persistentCookiesOnPassiveRedirects="true" issuer="http://something:97/QuadraSTSBeta/" realm="http://localhost:58663/" requireHttps="false" />
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was mainly caused by WebMatrix Data which was improperly trying to load user roles.

Because it was not used in the project, and there was no reason of its presence in this project, I decided to remove it.

Uninstalling the WebMatrix nuget, and removing ALL the references of WebMatrix inside the project resolved the issue.